# How do you create a signed loadable kernel module for Android?

Tags: android, kernel-module

I read what David Howells wrote on:
 https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/dhowells/linux-modsign/+/modsign-rusty/Documentation/module-signing.txt

I heard that the CONFIG_MODULE_SIG has to be turned on, but it was not stated particularly how. I am also not sure how to use a kernel make command.

I am not able to piece together enough information to generate a mini signed LKM.

Would anyone here have done it before, and able to guide me on a minimallist example on signing a helloworld LKM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For enabling CONFIG_MODULE_SIG, simply in configure file (.config), have this line:

```
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y
```

I've not tried, but I think even you can have CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y in make command like:

```
make CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y
```

For how to build a LKM for android, there is several tutorials in internet, for example take a look at this:
[How do you create a loadable kernel module for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282669/how-do-you-create-a-loadable-kernel-module-for-android)

Comment: the signature is still not embedded. I am not sure how to sign the module.

Comment: @UrsaMajor support for kernel signed modules started from Linux 3.7: http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.7, signing a kernel module for android is same as signing kernel module for linux. What is your linux kernel?

Comment: there is alot of description but unclear.
eg. set config. where? set what? which path?
eg. use this command. specifically how? 

Example is the best definition. It would be most efficient that way.

Thank you, 72DFBF5B A0DF5BE9, for your help.

+1 for you.

Comment: @UrsaMajor, just see this: http://yatsec.blogspot.com/2011/01/guide-to-compiling-custom-kernel.html there is much more, about CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y you can add it to Makefile or just in make command line as I said in my answer.

Comment: this is great !
They should do this. Very direct, clear and sweet.

Comment: @UrsaMajor, glad you liked it. Do you have any other question? Otherwise you can close this question

Comment: Hi @72DFBF5B A0DF5BE9, I am +50 bounty for you.
Please allow me to ask further question if I meet some blocking point in the process. Thank you.

Comment: @UrsaMajor, you are welcome, sure, just ask me here about upcoming problems/questions.

Comment: As a manual step, how may we create a linker command script to insert the signature manually into the ELF headers?
During runtime authentication, how may we read contents from the ELF header from the kernel module?

Comment: @UrsaMajor, for example you can see http://www.jukie.net/~bart/elfpgp/, also you can use signelf: http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1301.1/04326.html

Comment: how do we read the .rodata from the kernel? 
can you advise me on a code snippet?

Comment: do readelf -S, it will give you offset and size of rodata, just read that bytes: "# readelf -S yourbinary.elf"

Comment: also you can do: objdump -s -j .rodata elffile

Comment: @UrsaMajor, you need to write some special code for it if you want to extract .rodata of ELF, similar to objdump and readelf, you need to write your own code. Unless you are asking for something else, is it? If you are asking for something else, explain it, otherwise you need to write some codes similar to readelf to parse ELF header, find rodata section and extract bytes

Comment: yes, it is what I am asking. is there a code snippet for this?

Comment: gnu binutils contains objdump: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/, readelf source: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/elftoolchain/browser/trunk/readelf

Answer (score 1):

CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y only enables feature, to enforce it you also have to put CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE=y in the config file.

basically I found that there are three flags associated with this feature:
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y #to enable the feature
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL=y #to sign all the loadable modules during build process
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE=y #to enforce the feature so that no unsigned module can be loaded.