# Error while trying to compile android kernel code?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-firmware

I have been following this link [Android kernel compile and test with Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809774/android-kernel-compile-and-test-with-android-emulator) to compile the android source code.

But while trying to compile the source code using

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/lares/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.2.1/bin/arm-eabi-
```

I am getting this error.

```
lares@lares-Inspiron-1545:~/android_kernel$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/lares/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.2.1/bin/arm-eabi-
    make: execvp: /home/lares/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.2.1/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: Permission denied
    scripts/kconfig/conf -s arch/arm/Kconfig
    make[2]: execvp: scripts/kconfig/conf: Permission denied
    make[2]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 127
    make[1]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 2
      CHK     include/linux/version.h
    make[1]: `include/asm-arm/mach-types.h' is up to date.
    make: *** No rule to make target `include/config/auto.conf', needed by `include/config/kernel.release'.  Stop.
```

After fixing this by allocating permissions to appropriate directories i am getting this.

```
lares@lares-Inspiron-1545:~/android_kernel$ make ARCH=arm  CROSS_COMPILE=/home/lares/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.2.1/bin/arm-eabi-
    scripts/kconfig/conf -s arch/arm/Kconfig
      CHK     include/linux/version.h
    make[1]: `include/asm-arm/mach-types.h' is up to date.
      CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
      UPD     include/linux/utsrelease.h
      SYMLINK include/asm -> include/asm-arm
      CC      kernel/bounds.s
    arm-eabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
    make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 1
    make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

---

Can someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission for some (or all of) the path to `/home/lares/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.2.1/bin/arm-eabi-gcc` is not set for read plus execute.

If you have root access, check each path component and adjust appropriately.  Otherwise, get your sysadmin to fix it.

With that as the initial problem, the odds are rather high that there are other permission issues with the rest of the cross development tools, including the header files and libraries.

Comment: I have root access.Thanks.I will check and get back

Comment: Thanks i changed the permissions for the directory but now i got a new error.

Comment: The `cc1` executable file is missing from the appropriate `bin` directory.  Maybe you should re-install the toolchain?

Comment: Thanks .I am gonna look into it.

Comment: I didn't find the solution for the last error but Thanks for your help.It helped me get through the first one.