# How to update Android kernel with zImage?

Tags: android, kernel

I have changed Android kernel settings and re-built it.
I was trying to replace the original kernel installed on my device(Galaxy Tab 7.0) to the new kernel I built.

I have zImage on my host machine and I have sdcard in my device.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809774/android-kernel-compile-and-test-with-android-emulator