# How to modify Android emulator source code

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu

I would like to modify qemu source code to get some lower level information from Android emulator.

Where do I get Android emulator source code ? (I assume the source might include qemu source code as well).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Where do I get Android emulator source code

[It's here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#cZwlSNS7aEw/sdk/emulator/)

---

To build it : `build-emulator.sh`

which is located [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#cZwlSNS7aEw/external/qemu/distrib/build-emulator.sh&q=build-emulator.sh&exact_package=android&type=cs)

--- EDIT: now here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/master/docs/DEVELOPMENT.TXT

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I build the source code and get emulator binary?

Comment: I downloaded the source code and tried to built it. I got this error "build-emulator.sh: line 30: ./android-rebuild.sh: No such file or directory" Have you downloaded the source code and built it?

Comment: Last commit at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/master/docs/DEVELOPMENT.TXT in 2015, so I'm guessing it moved again...

Comment: No. They just stopped using master branch. See: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu.git/+/refs/heads/emu-master-dev

Comment: An old question, but: how do you import or open the sourcecode into an IDE? I need to search through files for references.