# Program a Android emulator

Tags: android

Does anyone know the start process of android emulator?I can find that a system.img file in my folder,and I often use emulator command to start a real emulator.Dose anyone know how the emulator command to load the system.img and how the emulator is manufactured?
Actually,I want to know how to program a emulator to load the android system.img by myself.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Android is open source, check the code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134089/android-emulator-source-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is command to start AVD with your own system.img

```
emulator -avd AVD_NAME -initdata userdata.img -ramdisk ramdisk.img -system system.img -sdcard ~/songs_for_music_app/Music_card.img
```

for source do `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk`
and follow [Modifying Android emulator source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134089/android-emulator-source-code) this.

or else follow this for whole android source  https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Comment: I want to know how to program the emulator command.

Comment: edited my ans :) hope u'll find wat u r lookin for :)

Comment: Ok,it's very useful,I want to use python to emulate a android emulator which has addtional function.Thanks a lot:)