# How to show which options are passed to QEMU when launching the android emulator?

Tags: android

I built AOSP `8.1.0_r60` from source, and launched it as explained at: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48310014/9

```
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_x86_64-eng
emulator -show-kernel
```

How can I now see all the command line options being passed to QEMU to better understand what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

**`-verbose`**

Just run with:

```
emulator -verbose
```

This makes the emulator command contains lines of form:

```
emulator: argv[00] = "/path/to/aosp/8.1.0_r60/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64"
emulator: argv[01] = "-dns-server"
emulator: argv[02] = "10.1.2.24,10.1.2.23"
emulator: argv[03] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[04] = "stdio"
```

which shows all the arguments given.