# Android Emulator source

Tags: android, android-source, qemu

I am trying to build the Android Emulator from source code for some University research, according to this [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134089/modifying-android-emulator-source-code) post the emulator is located [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/master/docs/DEVELOPMENT.TXT).

However I am skeptical if this still the source code Google uses to build the Android Emulator shipped with Android Studio as the `studio-*` branches have not been updated in several years. The `emu-*` branches have been updated recently, however they do not produce an emulator that similar to what is shipped with Android Studio.

Is the emulator open source still?

Comment: Did you manage to build the emulator only? and how?