# Where is the source code of the android emulator prebuilt?

Tags: android, emulation, qemu, kvm

According to [prebuilts/android-emulator/README](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/android-emulator/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r28/README):

> This directory contains prebuilt emulator binaries that were generated
> by running the following command on a 64-bit Linux machine:
> external/qemu/android/scripts/package-release.sh 
> --darwin-ssh= 
> --copy-prebuilts=

Which is also what I found in [Where is the Android emulator source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58714484/where-is-the-android-emulator-source-code) **but this repo is not updated since 2015**

So, where is the android emulator code hosted right now?

Comment: Thread of interest: [Reddit: r/androiddev: Did Google stop providing arm(64) images for emulators?](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9tu3nx/did_google_stop_providing_arm64_images_for/) and as you are looking at the QEMU stuff see [comment thread about about how slow it was](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9tu3nx/did_google_stop_providing_arm64_images_for/e922upt/)

Comment: But the Android emulator source code repo [external-qemu](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu) isn't as stale as you think it is: [aosp-emu-30-release](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/qemu-android-deps/+/refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release) and [emu-master-dev](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/refs/heads/emu-master-dev)