# Building AOSP and launching the emulator

Tags: emulation, android-source, building

I am trying to launch the emulator after building the Android source.

Right now, the setup is like, I am running a windows machine connecting through putty to my linux machine. I have downloaded my source in the linux machine and I have successfully built it.

When I am running the emulator using the command in

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9023141/539472

the emulator is launching but only the android image is coming. From there on the emulator is not completely booting. Its not going to launcher.

The logs are

`emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
Failed to create Context 0x3005`

There are many posts with this error, they say that check if the graphics driver is installed. I have checked it and its installed.

What might be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Putty is just terminal console, it has no graphics/windows it cant possibly display emulator. Emulator is application like Browser or GEdit. If you login to you linux machine directly using Ubuntu then it can show emulator application.