# Building android source and flashing it in emulator

Tags: android, makefile, build, android-emulator, android-source

I'm trying to build Android Nougat source following the instructions provided [here](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building). For the [source code and tags](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers#source-code-tags-and-builds) I'm not sure what to opt for so I opted for,

```
N2G48H  android-7.1.2_r36  Nougat  2017-10-05
```

`make` is successful it created image files within `out/target` directory. When I tried to flash it on emulator by simply typing `emulator` I'm seeing some weird device like this.

[image]

Got doubted on my target device type so tried following the instructions provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13266826/6680585) but still I'm seeing the same weird screen. Any help on this would be much appreciated.