# Working with Android ICS Source code - code overview needed

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-source

I successfully got and compiled android 4.0.3 on ubuntu 11.04.
all went fine (after alot of tries :) )
Now im looking for a code overview of the os. I understand the kernel is a different repo (got it also).
Tell me if i got it right - the kernel is ofcurse written in C, but is the entire OS except the core written in Java? i thought only the UI is written in Java and that theres alot of components below the dalvik.
I'm a C/C++ programmer. where do you suggest me to start looking?
I was planning to go over the kernel, but i dont have a test subject to debug it on.. im using the emulator.
  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the famous picture from android developers webpage:
[image: Android stack]

So, Linux Kernel is a Linux Kernel and written in C/C++. Libraries layer (green parts) are written also in C/C++. The libraries are external projects and just adopted for the use in Android. The sources of these libraries you can find in the `external` folder.

Android Runtime. DVM is written in C/C++.

All blue rectangles means that these components are written in Java. Application Framework is written in Java. The sources are in the `framewokrs` folder. But there are also code in this folder that is written in C/C++. Mostly these code is for JNI communication.

Answer (score 0):

Android is written in a mix of java, C and C++ . UI part is mostly done in Java and frameworks has a mix of java, C and C++. Components other than dalvik are also written in C/C++ . Many of the core services like ActivityManager , surfaceflinger , AudioFlinger are written in C and C++.

As far as linux kernel is concerned you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809774/android-kernel-compile-and-test-with-android-emulator) to get it working