# which files does an emulator need to run at least?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk

I have aready build a emulator with new kernel from source.

And with the built file and source,the project folder is so huge.So,i want to part them off.
Here,i download the sdk tools.

So,i wonder which files does a emulator need at least?such like,system.img and what?

(What's more,i have also build a new kernel,and i want to run the emulator with this new kernel)

thx,in advance!

attached:
After a long time searching,i put the minimal files in a folder like:

```
:~/droidls
hardware-qemu.img  system.img    userdata-qemu.img
ramdisk.img        userdata.img  zImage
```

And then,i cd to this folder and put the android-sdk-linx/tools path into host os's PATH variable.

At last,I try to use the following command to start the emulator:

```
emulator -kernel zImage -ramdisk ramdisk.img -sysdir ~/droid -datadir ~/droid -data userdata-qemu.img -system system.img -initdata userdata.img
```

But it fails.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> And with the built file and source,the project folder is so huge.

Please Describle it How the project folder got huge after built it.

> So,i wonder which files does a emulator need at least?such
>   like,system.img and what?

Yes, its nice question. as Per the Official Documentation,

> To use the emulator, you first must create one or more AVD
>   configurations. In each configuration, you specify an Android platform
>   to run in the emulator and the set of hardware options and emulator
>   skin you want to use. Then, when you launch the emulator, you specify
>   the AVD configuration that you want to load.
>
> Each AVD functions as an independent device, with its own private
>   storage for user data, SD card, and so on. When you launch the
>   emulator with an AVD configuration, it automatically loads the user
>   data and SD card data from the AVD directory. By default, the emulator
>   stores the user data, SD card data, and cache in the AVD directory.

you can Go through the [Here For More Description](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)

> What's more,i have also build a new kernel,and i want to run the
>   emulator with this new kernel

For query regarding Running with your New Kernal and running it with your emulator you can Go through  [Android Kernal Compile and Test with Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809774/android-kernel-compile-and-test-with-android-emulator)

Hope it Will Help

Answer (score -1):

For running an application on device or emulator `Android Package .apk` file is needed. A `.apk` files contains **.dex file(files converted to Dalvik byte code), resources files .arsc, Uncompiled resource and AndroidManifest.xml**. For more detail see the [developer guide document Building and Running](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html).