# How to start learning Android kernel development

Tags: android, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I will begin working under Android system kernel development and I have no ideas. All what I know is that I have to have knowledge on Linux, c and C++ and I have all of them but I should begin some trainings, so I need some first steps.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you all in advance

Comment: Read faq and first search, you can find helpful links here or on google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android kernels (and basic build instructions how to build them) can be found at http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html. You need a rootable phone to install the custom kernels, and I would recommend Linux as a developer platform. Maybe better to write some USB drivers for beginning.

Comment: Thank you Andrius, can you tell me what do you mean by rootable phone and how can I install my custom kernel (is it by using minicom for exapmle)?

Comment: Normally "Google developer phones" can be unlocked with some effort but without using security exploits. Google Galaxy Nexus is one of them. The new kernel can be installed using the firmware flash utility. See [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) for more about images and they flashing.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a root-able device, try working on building kernel for emulator. Here is the link the steps are clearly given. try on your linux host machine using these steps:

[Android kernel compile and test with Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809774/android-kernel-compile-and-test-with-android-emulator)

and

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-kernel/KsJhSEy4E1I

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will be helpful or not, but you might check with the silicon manufacturer that you are using, or wanting to use.  I know Freescale has complete Android build trees (including u-boot and Linux) available.  I would suspect that other companies would have similar build trees available, especially if they have reference platforms available for the particular silicon.  Outside of the phone market, Android itself is an embedded OS that has been included in such things as vending machines.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by silicon manufacturer? and what is its role in iOS? of course what do you mean by Freescale?