# Run custom ROM on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I downloaded a third-party ROM, and I want to run it on the emulator first before flash it into the phone. Here is the contents of `cm-11-20140911-NIGHTLY-p3110.zip`:

```
 1. boot.img
 2. file_contexts
 3. META-INF/
 4. recovery/
 5. system/
```

I unpacked `boot.img` using the script **`unpack-bootimg.pl`** and get `boot.img-kernel`, and `boot.img-ramdisk.cpio.gz.` Then I repacked the system using the **`make_ext4fs`** and got `system.img`.

I created an AVD and execute:

`emulator -system ~/cm11/system_new.img -ramdisk ~/cm11/boot.img-ramdisk.cpio.gz -kernel ~/cm11/boot.img-kernel -avd and442`

but all I got is nothing, the emulator screen is just black. There is no log message from `adb -s emulator-5554`.

Now I am confused:

- can the third-party ROM be tested by the emulator?
- Am I doing the right way?

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1599005

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: @Hrundi: only writing no. of lines of code is only programming?

Comment: @SanketPrabhu Changing a ROM is a generic system task, not related to programming

Comment: any updates? :( i am stuck with the same issue (built AOSP from source)

Comment: related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/how-to-flash-a-rom-to-the-android-emulator

Answer (score 12):

Yeah, why not.

**We can flash a third-party ROM on Android AVD.** But first you must know the following things:

**1. The Android Emulator is itself a device, like your [Moto G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_Moto#Moto_G) or [Xperia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Xperia)**

**2. Every ROM is device-specific (supports a device-specific Kernel)**

(on many sites/blogs you got information like you have to replace **system.img** file from .android\avd\avdname.avd, but it is technically incorrect, because you also require **ramdisk.img**.)

To do this, you need to create your own AOSP repository by downloading the particular repository and have to build your own .img files)

- **You can do it in two ways:**

1. replace files *system.img* and *ramdisk.img* from location                   *.android\avd\avdname.avd*
2. Build your own AOSP. Before... make in "lunch" select target as: Emulator (like: genericX86), i.e., generate all emulator specific .img files

**I have tried many things. It's a bit critical, but interesting. The following links may help you:**

[To run your cooked ROM on Emulator](http://techfutex.com/run-custom-rom-on-the-android-emulator/) (link down. Try [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160520153622/http://techfutex.com/run-custom-rom-on-the-android-emulator/), from archive.org).

[To Create AOSP Project](http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/144804-how-compile-ics-aosp-4-0-3-xoom-gnex-nexus-s.html)

Comment: Try this from archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20160520153622/http://techfutex.com/run-custom-rom-on-the-android-emulator/