# Creating an AVD and linking it to the AOSP

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-source

I am trying to use this tool GemDroid https://github.com/huz123/GemDroid_QEMU. I have downloaded the AOSP android-4.4.4_r2 and built it as well. According to the link above, an AVD has to be created using Android Studio, which I did but it give selective options to download a system image, say an Android 4.4.

1. My first question is how can I link the AVD to the AOSP I have
   downloaded? I tried pointing the location of the SDK to the AOSP
   location from Files>ProjectStructure in Android Studio but it says
   "SDK does not contain any platforms".
2. Is there a different way whereI can create an AVD directly from the
   directory of AOSP?
3. Or according to the step "start the emulator with 
   your android virtual device as usual" in the link above, how can I 
   start the emulator from AOSP with an AVD created using Android 
   Studio?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Please help, thanks!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985384/run-custom-rom-on-android-emulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the Android Studio for that - just go to your root directory and type in the command line:

```
emulator
```

If this doesn't work you probably had a problem in your build.([Build the AOSP](https://source.android.com/source/building.html))

Comment: I had trouble accessing the location of the emulator executable. Also I did not run `source build/envsetup.sh` prior to build. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I run the build

```
 source ./build/envsetup.sh
 lunch aosp_shamu-userdebug 

./prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator 
 -sysdir out/target/product/shamu/ 
 -system out/target/product/shamu/system.img  
 -ramdisk out/target/product/shamu/ramdisk.img 
 -data out/target/product/shamu/userdata.img 
 -kernel prebuilts/qemu-kernel/arm64/kernel-qemu 
 -scale 0.7 
 -memory 2048 
 -partition-size 4096 
 -no-window 
 -verbose
```