# How can I create an Xiaomi emulator for Android Studio? Or any other way to test app on Xiaomi emulators?

Tags: testing, android-emulator, xiaomi, redmi-device

I want to test my Android app for an Xiaomi device.

How can I create an emulator for that?

I have already tried [andyroid](https://www.andyroid.net/), [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) and [bluestack](https://www.bluestacks.com/), but I have not found any for Xiaomi devices.

Comment: You can use the AVD Manager that comes with Android Studio to create a virtual Redmi Note 5 Pro; I did this afternoon and it was very straightforward. The only problem is that Studio won't emulate MIUI, so unless that's important, go for it!

Comment: Have you find any solution for this after 2 years ?

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use some online device provider services like :  [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/test-on-xiaomi)
2. I never tried it but check out :   [Run custom ROM on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985384/run-custom-rom-on-android-emulator)
3. You can always borrow / buy an actual device.

Answer (score 2):

#### You can try `genymotion` but currently it has `Xiaomi Redmi Note 7`

[image]

Comment: It would be an alternative, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: This must be the accepted answer! This tool has plenty of free emulators.

Comment: **Genymotion's Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 runs vanilla Android, not MIUI**

Answer (score -5):

1. Menu *Tools* → *AVG Manager*
2. Click on "Create Virtual Device"
3. Select "Phone" in the left
4. Click "New Hardware Profile" button below
5. Use the following information in the next screen:

   Device Name: Redmi Note 5 
   Device Type: Phone/ Tablet 
   Screen Size: 5.99 Inch 
   Resolution: 1080 x 2160 px 
   Memory: 4 GB 
   Input: <Leave these un-selected> 
   Rest of the fields: keep as is.

   Save it and select it.
6. Click "Next" below to go to the next page "Select a system image".
   Select the Release you want. E.g., Oreo [Target: Android 8.1].
   Click "Next" to "Verify Configuration".
   Name the AVD - something like "Redmi Note 5 Oreo"

Finish.

Enjoy!!

Comment: Does that create an emulator for an Xiaomi device?

Answer (score -26):

Here are the steps with Android Studio:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Modern problem requires Modern solution !!

Comment: @kelvin: What do you mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: This is a terrible answer. I have faced specific issues with MIUI, FireOS, and EMUI. How did I face them? Because I distributed my Android apps in other stores and there my apps crashed. In EMUI there was a very specific library for handling JSONs that was incompatible. In FireOS I had to change the geo-location methods and in MIUI I'm still struggling to get an answer from the support team because my app works perfectly fine in FireOS, One UI, pure Android, ColorOS, and MIUI but it's crashing in EMUI.