# Flashing android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to flash android emulator from android studio. I know that in common device I can run adb reboot bootloader and then fastboot flashall -w, but I have no idea how I can flash emulator. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run custom ROM on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985384/run-custom-rom-on-android-emulator)

Comment: By flash you mean remove all data?