# Tips and tricks useful to "checkout" (download) the Android source code more quickly

Tags: android, git, diskspace, repo, sparse-checkout

Viewing and searching the Android source code is simple.  You simply visit the [AndroidXRef](http://androidxref.com) website.

But, if you want to build and run the [bleeding-edge version of Superuser](https://github.com/phhusson/Superuser), you [must](https://github.com/koush/Superuser/issues/283#issuecomment-137088862) first download an entire Android source tree.

Imagine that I want to grab the Android "master" branch from source control.

If I follow [Google's official instructions](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html):

- The operation will definitely take at least an hour.  It may take [half a day or more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046570/what-does-repo-init-and-repo-sync-actually-do).
- It will probably pull in [tens of gigabytes of data](https://superuser.com/questions/603547/how-can-i-limit-the-size-of-the-android-source-i-need-to-download-with-repo-sync).  Where I live, ISPs sometimes charge an "overage fee" when users pull in tens of gigabytes of data in one month.  I don't enjoy paying fees or surcharges.

In short, doing an ordinary `repo sync` command would probably be slow and wasteful.  I don't need the entire history of Android development; and I don't have infinite disk space.

How can I check out the Android source code more quickly?

1. I know that doing a "shallow clone" would help.  How can I do this?
2. [Rakesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1493534/rakesh) writes, [elsewhere](https://superuser.com/questions/603547/how-can-i-limit-the-size-of-the-android-source-i-need-to-download-with-repo-syn#966154), that `repo sync -c` will help.  Will it?  I've read the [documentation](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/subcmds/sync.py#146) for the `-c` option.  But I don't understand Git well enough to know whether or not the option will actually help at all.  Here's a [related discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.repo/2680).
3. (Optional:)  Are there any other tips or tricks which can I use to speed up the checkout operation?
4. (Optional:)  In the end, how much disk space will I require in order to hold the checked-out code?

P.S.  I thank durron597 for the advice s/he gave me in chat last week.  Any resulting improvements which have been made to this question are all thanks to him/her.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe passing `--depth=1` to `repo init` would help.

Comment: That's how I always did a shallow clone, I'd assume it will still work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AOSP repo sync takes too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379870/aosp-repo-sync-takes-too-long)

Answer (score 0):

1. `repo init --depth=1` (according to `repo help init`)
2. `-c` downloads only current branch. Only useful if you don't use `--depth` because `depth` implies `-c` (according to `git help clone`)
3. I just downloaded it (20-07-2017) and the history takes up 21GB. I have checked out the `studio-master-dev` branch, which takes up another 15GB. So in total 36GB.