# How to build Android system.img and run it on emulator?

Tags: linux, windows, image, emulation

I have just compiled the AOSP and copied system.img to Android SDK directory on Windows. But the emulator can't boot the virtual device.
Anyone knows why?

Comment: xdescription  "But the emulator can't boot the virtual device" is not enough to provide any good answer

short and too general answer is "follow instruction from https://source.android.com/setup/build/building "

> Emulate an Android device
The emulator is added to your path automatically by the build process. To run the emulator, type: emulator

also try use linux instead of Windows

Comment: Here is a detailed working setup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809774/how-to-compile-the-android-aosp-kernel-and-test-it-with-the-android-emulator/48310014#48310014

Answer (score 4):

**Build ASOP and run on emulator**

Build an AVD system image. This is the same process as building an Android device system image. For example, to build a x86 ([Check this](https://source.android.com/setup/create/avd))

```
$ cd aosp-master
$source ./build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch sdk_phone_x86
$ make -j32

$ make -j32 sdk sdk_repo

$ cd ./out/host/linux-x86/sdk/sdk_phone_x86
```

You can see the build system images zip file as follows

```
$ ls
```

sdk-repo-linux-system-images-eng.[username].zip

extract the above zip

you can add to . ~/.bashrc or just type on terminal

```
$ export ANDROID_SDK=<Path_to_SDK>
$ export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/emulator:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$PATH
```

go to extracted folder

```
$ cd <extracted 
sdk-repo-linux-system-images-eng.[username]>
```

you can see image files in folder(./x86)

Create AVD by android studio.
Go to Android Studio-> tools-> avd manager->create virtual device
lets say we created Pixel_2_API_29

check available android virtual devices

```
$ emulator -list-avds
```

Pixel_2_API_29

then run build ASOP images on emulator

```
$ emulator -sysdir <Path_to_images> -avd <Created_AVD>
```

ex:

```
$emulator -sysdir <Patth_To_Extracted_Images/x86> -avd Pixel_2_API_29
```